# Hiding Vim .ext~ files in Windows

Tags: windows, vim

When i use vim on windows, i realize that vim saves the file
and closing the vim window deletes a .ext.swp file amd a .ext~ file

How do i disable or delete these files as the duplicates are causing my problems
as i work on my host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743150/how-to-prevent-vim-from-creating-and-leaving-temporary-files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off the vim swap files and backup files to disable the creation of these files:

`:set noswapfile` and `:set nobackup`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821902/disabling-swap-files-creation-in-vim) for more information.