# Development server of create-react-app does not auto refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am following a [tutorial](https://egghead.io/courses/react-fundamentals) on React using create-react-app. 
The application is created by [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) v1.3.0

```
create-react-app my-app
```

The dev server is run by

```
npm start
```

After changing the code several times, the browser is not updated live / hot reload with the changes. Refreshing the browser does not help. Only stopping the dev server and starting it over again capture the new changes to the code.

Comment: Are you accessing your app through `http://localhost:3000/`?

Comment: @JoeClay Yes. And the browser start and shows the page. It page itself does not get change with new editing to the code.

Comment: This was the only solution I could find that works on Windows 10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/52231731/74585

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Have you seen the “Troubleshooting” section of the User Guide?
It describes [a few common causes of this problem](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-start-doesnt-detect-changes):

> When you save a file while `npm start` is running, the browser should refresh with the updated code.
>
> If this doesn’t happen, try one of the following workarounds:
>
> - If your project is in a Dropbox folder, try moving it out.
> - If the watcher doesn’t see a file called `index.js` and you’re referencing it by the folder name, you [need to restart the watcher](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1164) due to a Webpack bug.
> - Some editors like Vim and IntelliJ have a “safe write” feature that currently breaks the watcher. You will need to disable it. Follow the instructions in [“Disabling swap files creation in vim”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821902/disabling-swap-files-creation-in-vim).
> - If your project path contains parentheses, try moving the project to a path without them. This is caused by a [Webpack watcher bug](https://github.com/webpack/watchpack/issues/42).
> - On Linux and macOS, you might need to [tweak system settings](https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#not-enough-watchers) to allow more watchers.
> - If the project runs inside a virtual machine such as (a Vagrant provisioned) VirtualBox, create an `.env` file in your project directory if it doesn’t exist, and add `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to it. This ensures that the next time you run `npm start`, the watcher uses the polling mode, as necessary inside a VM.
>
> If none of these solutions help please leave a comment [in this thread](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/659).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, you were dead on. I was using Vim. Setting `set backupcopy=yes` fixed the problem, as said in the provided links to the docs.

Comment: > On Linux and macOS, you might need to tweak system settings to allow more watchers.
This one was the problem in my case. I've followed https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/04/native-file-system-watcher-for-linux/ to fix it (it helped even I don't use IntelliJ)

Comment: I am using VirtualBox and this solution "create  .env file in your project directory if it doesn’t exist, and add CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true to it" ,  worked for me. thank you so much

Comment: Create .env file work for me since I am working on VM

Comment: `:wq` will help you checking whether it is the vim-related problem.

Comment: if the CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true does the trick for you consider using another  env variable CHOKIDAR_INTERVAL=2000 . This limits the amount of CPU used by CHOKIDAR polling method

Comment: I am in elementary os and creating a .env file helped me. thanks

Comment: Hi Dan, Would you please explain more what really chokidar is?

Comment: moving it out of Dropbox didn't make a difference for me

Comment: The `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` solution worked for me when using React inside a Docker container. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like they moved the troubleshooting webpage. Would you mind updating the link?

Answer (score 156):

I was reading a lot of unnecesary stuff.

I am using **React 17**.

And my problem was that the page just add new components but the browser was not refreshing the page.

If your terminal is `Compiling...` and then you don't see changes on the browser, you should try adding a `.env` file in the root path of the project and add `FAST_REFRESH=false`.

Hot refresh was replaced by Fast refresh by default.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me on React 17.0.1

Comment: This works for me on Windows with React 17.0.1. Thanks!

Comment: This was the answer for me too!  Very counter intuitive that marking "Fast_Refresh=false" causes it to quickly refresh on its own

Comment: Thanks! Works on React 17.0.2 too

Comment: Documentation is here - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/.
FAST_REFRESH - has to be over-ridden to false else the browser does not refresh for some changes. From the documentation -  "When set to false, disables experimental support for Fast Refresh to allow you to tweak your components in real time without reloading the page?

Comment: Remember to restart the app once you add the `.env` file, otherwise, it will not work immediately.

Comment: Perfect, this fixes it for me on React 17.0.2 on MacOS.

Answer (score 84):

Adding a `.env` file in the base path of the project and inside add `FAST_REFRESH=false`.

This disables fast refresh and returns to hot reload.

If you don't want to add a .env file to your base path you can choose these options:

- `"start": "FAST_REFRESH=false react-scripts start"`, in the package.json.
- `FAST_REFRESH=false npm run start`, on the command line.
- `FAST_REFRESH=false`, exporting it as an environment variable.

> React 17
>
> React-scrits 4

Comment: This works on my Mac finally. Everything else didint. Only adding this one helps. Do somebody knows a root cause of this?

Comment: This worked for me also working on a headless cloud listening on 0.0.0.0

Comment: Correct answer - MacOSX React app typescript

Comment: Did the trick for me (Ubuntu 20.04.2 and Firefox 84.02)

Comment: This works fine on Win10. To create a .env file in Win10 create a new file and rename it <blank>.env

Comment: @Hrabosch This is due to the new version of React 17. It changed the hot reload for the fast refresh, and there are still things to polish it.

Comment: Worked. I'm surprised there isn't an open issue on github or something.

Comment: 'FAST_REFRESH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program, or batch file. Giving an error when I run npm start with the first option.

Answer (score 34):

Have you tried npm start with super user permissions? I had the issue with my project and I solved it like this.

```
$sudo bash
#npm  start
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This did not work. Not in sudo, nor under root user.

Comment: Very much appreciate your effort. It solved my issue after hours of debugging

Comment: If `npm start` requires superuser permissions, something is very wrong (or you're trying to bind to a privileged port). Before running as superuser, be sure to find out why you need to do so.

Answer (score 26):

In WSL2 work for me, "If the project runs inside a virtual machine such as (a Vagrant provisioned) VirtualBox, create an `.env` file in your project directory if it doesn’t exist, and add `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` to it. This ensures that the next time you run `npm start`, the watcher uses the polling mode, as necessary inside a VM."

Or just run:
`$ CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true npm start`

Comment: This was the fix for me, but I actually needed to add this env config to my `docker-compose.yml` so it ultimately said `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: 'true'` under the `environment` section

Comment: I was using WLS and this was the fix for me. Cheers

Comment: After trying everything else (on WSL2), using `$ CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true npm start` is what finally worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

Spent few hours fixing this:

---

1 . Create a file .env (beside package.json file) add below contents:

File: .env

```
FAST_REFRESH=false
```

2 . Now, stop & start the server

```
(Ctrl + C to start, if in CMD, on Windows OS)
npm start
```

4 . Now, change some text in the App.js

File: App.js

```
from "Learn React"
to "Learn React And it's working"
```

NOTE:
1 . Server restart is important.
2 . Refresh browser tab if you dont see changes.

Comment: How would you do this in Typescript?

Comment: It is creating `.env` file, and adding that line. I guess that should not change if we use TS instead of JS, try creating that file, it might work, else there might be something else going on specific to our project.

Comment: Oops, yeah you are correct. I just had another error in my file which was preventing the auto reload. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

In my case, it was there are not enough number of file watchers. I have to change the configurations manually.

See active file watchers limit using below command on terminal.

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Add below line to the **/etc/sysctl.conf** file.

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

Apply changes using the command below.

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: this was my problem too! now resolved. thanks to this answer.

Comment: this worked for a while. after a few hours it stopped again. why is this happening anyway

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem while running `npm` within WSL. I had the project folder in my windows Desktop folder from which npm cannot recompile automatically in WSL.
After **moving the project folder to user `home` directory of WSL** solved the issue.

Comment: Nice, the issue with that is that you have to constantly save your code to GIT if you are just trying stuff and you don't want to use GIT and just have it in a different disk where you have all your stuff....

Answer (score 8):

just create `.env` file in the **root** of your app
and add the following to it

.env

```
FAST_REFRESH=false
```

Answer (score 7):

On win10 in WSL2, I had to create the .env in the root folder, and include both

```
FAST_REFRESH = false
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

My setup doesn't include any virtual machine (unless WSL2 is considered a VM?). Nevertheless the .env with the above two entries got it up and running.

Answer (score 6):

As of react-scripts version 5.x.x `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` no longer works in a .env file. You now need to use `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` in the .env file in the root of your project. [Per this thread.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10253)

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. This was the solution for this kind of problem with Win10 PRO/WSL2 and react-scrips 5.0.1. Excellent !!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Find your `index.js` and change something in this file, for example add a white space, then save.
It should show "compiling..." in your console.

Then you can modify other files and react will refresh on save.

It seems that npm is looking for changes in the index.js at the very first time, if you refactor your folder structure the index.js could be missed. **Force an update in index.js file get the problem solved.**

At least this has worked to me

Answer (score 4):

For users of WSL2, be mindful that if your project is in your Windows System(ie C: or D:) then it won't work.

Solution 1:

access these files through the WSL share, \wsl$\DISTRO_NAME from Windows.

Solutions 2:

Inside your package.json

find

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

and replace it with

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Credits to https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10253

Comment: could you explain the first solution? My projects/todo-calendar folder is placed on Desktop. I tried 2nd solution didn't work.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (WSL 2 user)

Comment: Now `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` is to be set, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10253#issuecomment-1127340307

Answer (score 3):

If you are using visual studio code, you can create a new file and save it as `.env`. Inside, `.env` write `FAST_REFRESH=false` and save. Then, run `npm start` and this worked for me.

Comment: what does visual studio code have to to?

Answer (score 3):

In case people come here looking for a better solution, my issue was resolved by moving my files inside the WSL2 filesystem. Hot reloading worked straight away with no need to add an .env file.

Comment: I moved all of the 41,150 files that my hello world application created and this worked for me.   So when my repo was on Onedrive it didn't refresh, but when it was inside WSL, it refreshes properly.

Answer (score 2):

You might wanna add -w to {"start": "react-scripts start -w"}.
I had the same issue, fixed by adding --watch.

Comment: adding -w did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: This might not be a recommended solution. The solution worked for Docker.

If using docker with a volume mount, you need to add an .env file in the src folder with the command `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` in it. However, for me this threw an error

> /app/src/App.js: Cannot find module '@babel/parser'

. To resolve this new error, changing the `"react-scripts": "3.4.3"` to  `"react-scripts": "3.4.0"` in the package.json file worked. So you depending on your situation you may need to add the .env file and also change the react-scripts version.

*Note: To put a little more context, I was working with docker and the react app files were mounted as a volume in the docker image (so that making changes in the app are directly reflected in the app without rebuilding a docker image). The above solution is based on other solutions posted in the community  for docker where people had suggested changing the react scripts version. I don't think this should be a recommended solution. However, since I was doing a tutorial series I wanted to save time and focus on other things.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your app behind a reverse proxy / nginx (e.g. to enable https locally) you also need to enable websockets so it can detect the refresh:

```
location /sockjs-node {
    proxy_pass http://dockerhost:5000/sockjs-node;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In package.json, use "react-scripts": "3.4.4"
2. Delete package-lock.json
3. Run "rm -rf node_modules && npm install"

npm start

Answer (score 1):

I was confused about how to create a .env file and even when i did it still didn't work. I was able to fix the issue by running this command on my terminal.

```
npm run start -FAST_REFRESH=false
```

Hopes it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here seeking answers to a similar issue. Although mine was specific to one page that wasn't hot reloading. I do want to point out this is using Nextjs and it was a page under /pages named subscribe.js (/pages/subscribe.js)

It was very frustrating and admittedly took a while to figure out.

A lot of technical answers here, but interestingly, my issue was that my functional component did not start with a capital letter.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function subscribe() {
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

Where the function name needed to start with a capital like so

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Subscribe() {
  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

As they say, you learn something new every day. In this game it's more like 10 things, the trouble is remembering what you learn ;)

Answer (score 0):

push your commited changes to the branch and then delete the local repo folder then clone the repo again and run `npm install` or `yarn install` whichever you prefer.
this workaround solved my issue

Comment: There is no mention about any VCS. If I understand it correctly you only suggestion reinstall libraries, or I am wrong?

Comment: It didn't work form me :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 
sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

If still, the error is there then you need to remove your node modules and again

```
npm install
```

and then

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating a new project using [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) toolchain

Make sure to run

1. `npm install`, then
2. `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

"dependencies": {
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
}
if you are using these version then create .env file on the root directory of your project and type FAST_REFRESH=false and save it. Then yarn start OR npm start.

Answer (score 0):

for linux first check the number of the files allowed using:

> cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

in my, it was 8192 so I just change it to 524288 and it worked perfectly.

commands use to change is:

> cd /proc/sys/fs/inotify
> sudo nano max_user_watches

and then change no to 524288
save it and then use this command to apply the changes

> sudo sysctl -p

reference from https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/04/native-file-system-watcher-for-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Watch out where you add your .env file to. When you call `create-react-app app-name`,  React will add following folder structure:

```
./root
   ./app-name
      ./node_modules
      ./public
      ./src
      package.json
      README.md
```

My problem was, I added .env file (with `FAST_REFRESH=false` inside) under the ./root directory. Placing the file in my ./app-name folder solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above suggestions, but still my react app does not refresh on code changes. Then I copied the previously working react project folder (only frontend) pasted it into the new project I am starting. Removed all the code related to old project and started using it.  This solved my problem.

If this is feasible for you, you too can adopt the same method. If anyone discover a new simple solution, please post it here.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention that I was using WSL2. And I was already using package.json file with the following line in package.json under scripts:  "start": "CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start",

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30896213)

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `npm build` everytime I wanted to refresh the app. Reinstalling node and npm didn't help. The project used a build tool called Parcel. Deleting the auto generated files such as `.parcel-cache` and `dist` resolved the issue for me.

My solution was to delete auto generated untracked/ignored files. The following git command might help:
`git status --ignored`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found a rather simple solution. Turns out I didn't `ctrl + S` my work.  Make sure to turn on `auto save` in the code editor. It compiled my react project after every change I made and displayed those changes on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

change the start

"scripts": {

```
"start": "export PORT=4000 && react-scripts start -w",
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8068 build",
"buildWin": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

},

Answer (score 0):

I am using React in the Yarn workspace with CRACO & TypeScript.
Adding `transpileOnly` option worked for me.

```js
{
       test: /\.ts$/,
       use: {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
              options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
              },
       },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone using Windows that none of the previous answers worked: **make sure to check your directory path**

The directories path should **NOT HAVE**:

- Any space
- Special Characters like ! or #

I had this issue (webpack was also showing "Compiling with 1 error" on console) because one of my directories was starting with #.

You don't need to reinstall anything, just close your editor, fix the incorrect directory, and open the project again on your editor from the new folder path, and live reload should work now.

Answer (score -1):

If you are on linux, check if it works with root access. If it does, stop your server and disable enforcement (for more details, `man selinux`).

```sh
sudo setenforce 0
```

Start your server again (without root), it might work.

Answer (score -1):

I came up against this same problem when starting the server through `npm run start`. When I changed it to `npm start`, it worked as expected.

Answer (score -6):

Instead of

```
npm start
```

Run with administration permission
in Linux

```
sudo npm start
```

Comment: what's your reasoning behind using `sudo` with npm?

Answer (score -7):

For Linux system you can try

```
sudo npm start
```

Comment: Suggestions to use sudo with npm should include a warning about the security risks of doing so.

Comment: Use the sudo command is a very irresponsability