# Auto reload react server on update

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm new to React. I'm having some problems with react server. After starting the server by `npm start` if I work on the source code and make some changes, I have to stop the server and restart it to make that change available on the browser. Is there anyway to make it auto compile and refresh the browser on update ? (Like `nodemon` for node ?)

Comment: I normally use `nodemon` with `babel-node`. Looks like there may be other solutions out there. Haven't tried this, but: https://github.com/kmagiera/babel-watch

Comment: yea @Jacob , even I'm using nodemon for Node server. But is it possible to use nodemon for react too ? 
And I tried installing babel-watch. But it gives me some errors. I'll check that out. Thanks

Comment: You can see this answer, it can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/65171489/13801206

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar (or event the same) problem and I changed starting command in the  `package.json` file by adding following flags: `--watch --watch-poll` to the `webpack-dev-server`:

```
{
    //...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --env.ENVIRONMENT=development --content-base src/ --mode development --watch --watch-poll",
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now, using `npm start` and then changing src files I can see changes in the browser.

Please here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/ for more options.

Comment: Worked by adding --watch --watch-poll

Comment: I get the following error after `npm start`: [webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--env.ENVIRONMENT=development'