# React-create-app index.js file doesn't reload automatically

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using React version 17.0.1 on windows and I've noticed that the `create-react-app` hot reload doesn't work. I found some tips online ([Development server of create-react-app does not auto refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274925/development-server-of-create-react-app-does-not-auto-refresh) for example ) and tried every one of them (my path doesn't include parentheses, it isn't synced to google drive or dropbox, I've tried the watcher refresh and reinstalling the node modules). Nothing worked until I realized  that the problem occurs **only** with the index.js file. If I save any other file (html or components) the browser does reload automatically. I've read that this might be a bug with the newer version of React that was released just days before I started studying this subject.

One thing I should mention is that my `npm start` script (that was automatically generated) is different than the ones I saw on the other threads ([Auto reload react server on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879098/auto-reload-react-server-on-update) for example), It doesn't says "Webpack" at all and I thought it maybe have something to do with my problem.
From the package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Is there any way around this bug? Is this problem familiar?

Comment: you can see this answer can serve you as it uses react 17 https://stackoverflow.com/a/65171489/13801206