# When using create-react-app why does the development server keep disconnecting?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

It happens arbitrarily, like once every 3 or 4 refreshes, the server just disconnects with this message in the console:

```
The development server has disconnected.
Refresh the page if necessary.
```

I looked at one of the other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274925/development-server-of-create-react-app-does-not-auto-refresh) and my problem seems different because that's about the webpack watcher not connecting, to begin with, in my case it works but disconnects very often. I haven't even ejected the app so not sure why this can be.

Comment: Not sure. But better if you post your webpack.config file here.

Comment: @User3250 I don't have access to that since I haven't ejected create-react-app. CRA hides those files so the user doesn't tamper with them unless you eject.

Comment: Post a link to your repo so we can try it locally

Comment: Hey OP.  Are you doing anything non-default in the setup?  Got anything weird in your appsettings.json?  Where are you running it from?  Just command line?  VS code?

Comment: Also can you try updating the version of Chrome you're using - can be done from the settings page in the browser

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Presuming you're using chrome, try updating the browser.  Last time I saw this, updating either fixed it, or cleared the issue causing it

Comment: Are you perhaps using HTTPS or have some custom reverse proxy settings?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question,but for me most of the time when I get that error it's because of an infinite loop

Comment: Oddly enough for me, i had this error message every time I clicked a button on a form.  I had a `handleClick(event)` method associated to the form.  I just added this line in the method `event.preventDefault()` and I no longer got that error message.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Chrome, this might be connected to `webpack-dev-server` (which create-react-app uses under the hood) issue described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1491).

Since this has been already addressed by create-react-app team, 
check the latest available version of `react-scripts` here: [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), bump the `react-scripts` version in your `package.json` to match it and run `npm install` (or `yarn install`) in your project's folder to update to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this when the page was trying to render a huge load of data. Paginated the table and everything worked fine.