# Issue about installation of New React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I want to learn React. so I installed Nodejs(v 10.16.0 LTS) and then using Windows Powershell I run following commands

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

After installing, When I try to make a change in any code (like changing page title name), after saving code file. The Tab in Browser does not reload automatically and when I reload tab manually the error occurs which say

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
>
> Checking the proxy and the firewall.

If I start this using PowerShell using **npm start*** command, then it run successfully. but I have to do this every time even when I edit my code. Browser tab did not reload and apply changes automatically.

Kindly guide me about this issue. Thanks

Comment: Can you share your command's logs?

Comment: Just to check, after `npm start`, can you see the app running properly the first time?

Comment: @rdarioduarte Yes, after 'npm start, app run properly the first time only.

Comment: Check privileges... Maybe `my-app` folder is `read-only`

Comment: @DennisVash Can you guide me how to check and change privileges?

Comment: I'm not a windows user so you can google it, it should be in folder properties (right-click on the folder)

Comment: On which port your project is running for first time?

Comment: @ravibagul91 http://localhost:3000/

Comment: Do one thing. Create `.env` file in your project's root folder with `PORT=3001`. And restart your app.

Comment: Hope this one be helpful.
**Try this**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281575/7363136

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `react-hot-loader` in your project react doesn't come with hot reload you need to include it in your project below is the link to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hot-loader) please go through the documentation they provide once, and add it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `react-hot-loader` or anything else if you've created your react app through `create-react-app` - just make sure you're using the latest stable version of `create-react-app`

In your react app, when you run `npm start`, it uses `react-scripts start` script  which behind the scenes uses `webpack` which actually takes care of hot module replacement

The problem you're facing seems most likely related to your local setup. Can you try running your app on a different port `8080` maybe?

Secondly, hot module replacement uses a websocket connection, can you check in your console if there is any error related to ws connection?