# Local Server Auto Refresh of create-react-app is not working in my VM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

Local Server Auto Refresh of create-react-app is not working in my Virtual Machine: When I update my code, the server is not auto updating.

I'm using Ubuntu as OS and VSCode to write code and the VSCode terminal to run the app locally.

The command to local startup:
`npm start`

Answer (score 0):

I created an .env and add CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true to it.
Why? This ensures that the next time of run npm start, the watcher uses the polling mode, as necessary inside a VM.

Got this from here:
[Development server of create-react-app does not auto refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274925/development-server-of-create-react-app-does-not-auto-refresh)

And up the answer.