# React app won't reload after redux install

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refresh

Yesterday I installed redux in my React project, and the app suddently stopped to refresh when I save a file.
I tried following the suggestions in this post, but nothing works: [Development server of create-react-app does not auto refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274925/development-server-of-create-react-app-does-not-auto-refresh)

I also noticed that if I add an import declaration on the top of my file which is **not used**, the browser console shows the "unused import warning" when I save the file, but the App itself is not reloading automatically.

Comment: Check the `max_user_watches` as [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60500802/14705483)

Comment: Those commands are not working in my console, it says they do not exist.