# react auto reload not working for changes made in index.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a new react app using the following command:

```
npx create-react-app app-name.
```

- opened the newly created app in VSCode.
- started the app by running the command: `npm start`
  app started correctly.

When i try to make any change in `index.js` (add a new paragraph or text),the changes are not reflected on the UI.The changes appear only when i refresh page by my self.
Is this problem related to FAST-REFRESH,and how can it be fixed?

Comment: It seems like there are already some comments on this problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274925/development-server-of-create-react-app-does-not-auto-refresh

Comment: Thanks a lot,if somebody has the same problem with newer versions of react(17+),you can check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66181863/15271439