# JavaScript/CSS styles are not refreshing after save in IDE

Tags: c#, css, reactjs, .net, typescript

Yesterday everything was fine, all worked. But today I wanted to develop my app, and I noticed that after save (Ctrl + S) my page does not update. It is very annoying, because I have to use F5, which is kinda slow. I run whole app (backend <.NET> + frontend )

I dont know what happened, as I said - yesterday everything worked, I haven't made any changes in code, IDE (Rider).

Also I tried to run on another IDE (VSC) but it doesn't work as well.
I tried to run only the frontend and suprisingly - **it worked!**

Do you have any ideas how I can check whats happening?

Comment: This is exactly how it intend to be. When you run react only, hot-reload is handled by CRA. But when you serve all from your .net server then ofc no hot-reload there

Comment: but since today all worked perfecly, so why did it change?

Comment: If anybody would have had similad problem - [This sovled my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374068/asp-net-6-with-reactjs-browser-not-refreshing-on-hot-reload-with-react-scripts)