# create-react-app v5.0.0 not reloading on WSL

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Before the release of v5.0.0 `create-react-app`, I used to able to have the hot loading/refreshing of my work by creating a `.env` file and putting the following CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

Since the release, this is no longer working and have yet to find a workaround.
I have also tried putting FAST_REFRESH=false

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that this recent problem is caused by any of the *other* issues mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281575/11810933)?

Answer (score 0):

I also use WSL and I too had the same problem. I read somewhere (can't get back that link) that if we keep our code in ubuntu or that Linux related file system, it works. I moved my code from my D: or so, to /home directory of ubuntu and subfolders. Magically, it started reloading after every change, without any other tip like using CHOKIDAAR, or using .env file, etc.