# Fast Refresh not happening using React js and Django

Tags: reactjs, django

Im very new to react js and Django and i want to experiment how the screen changes whenever i save the codes. But currently whenever i do the changes, i need to press the refresh button on the browser manually to check the changes.
After a lot of research i found the way to automatically do that is via Fast Refresh.
I have tried a lot of things for it to work using the links below but none have worked so far.

https://dev.to/thestl/react-fast-refresh-in-django-react-kn7
[Development server of create-react-app does not auto refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274925/development-server-of-create-react-app-does-not-auto-refresh)

I am using webpack 5.88.2, babel/core 7.22.20,react 18.2.0

Please let me know how i can do this.
Thanks